# Newly created team in team project cannot be accessed

Tags: tfs

## Problem

So I'm on TFS 2017.1 and running a 1 Team Project - multiple Teams configuration via `https://<hostname>:443/`.

There are already some teams with own Tfs-Groups, permissions, Area Paths, etc.
Each team is configured equally:

- Team with team members (e.g. NewTeam)
- Group for permissions (e.g Contributors_NewTeam)
- Area path for team (e.g. Development/NewTeam)

All of these existing teams were created before 2017.1 and are working as expected.

When I added another team and tested access with a new user. Tfs is not showing the team in web access for this user:

[image: NoTeams]

With my own user I can view and access the team just fine:

[image: MyselfTeams]

When the user is added to any other existing team he suddenly can see the newly created team and also access it.

---

## Configuration

Configuration for "NewTeam" is as follows:

Team is created and user is added:
[image: TeamPofile]

Tfs-Group is created and permissions are set as needed:
[image: SecurityContributorsPermissions]

Team is inheriting permissions from Tfs-Group:
[image: SecurityTeamPermissions]

Team is member of Tfs-Group:
[image: SecurityTeamMemberOf]

Tfs-Group is member of "Project Valid Users":
[image: SecurityContributorsMemberOf]

Tfs-Group is added to area path and permissions are set as needed:
[image: AreaPathSecurity]

---

## Findings so far:

When looking at the web api requests sent to fetch the groups following error is returned from tfs:

```
 {
     "$id":"1",
     "InnerException":null,
     "Message":"TF14045: The identity with TeamFoundationId <guid> could not be found.",
     "TypeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityNotFoundException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi",
     "TypeKey":"IdentityNotFoundException",
     "ErrorCode":0,
     "EventId":4207
 }
```

Which after some googling should be read as: `Not found or no sufficient permissions for team.`

When looking into the event log on the tfs server the following error appeared when trying to access the team dashboard directly via url:

```
Ausnahmemeldung: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Typ NullReferenceException)
Ausnahmestapelüberwachung:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Dashboards.DashboardSecurityNamespaceHelper.GetTeamMemberGroupPermissions(IVssRequestContext requestContext, Guid teamId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Dashboards.Services.DashboardService.GetDashboardGroup(IVssRequestContext requestContext, IDashboardConsumer dashboardConsumer)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Presentation.DashboardsViewHelper.GetViewModel(TfsWebContext tfsWebContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Presentation.DashboardsController.Index()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

But I think this is just a consequence of the web api call returning no info for the team and the subsequent call then passing `null` as the id.

## What I tried:

- I compared, multiple times..., that all permissions of "NewTeam" match with already existing and working teams. So permissions *should* be correct.
- I tried restarting the server
- I tried restarting tfs services via quiesce / unquiesce
- I tried creating another team, also multiple times..., in case I missed something.
- I looked into the tfs project collection database and found that `[tbl_Area]` does contain paths for the existing teams but not for the newly created team. But I did not find out why.
- I tried using another test user in case something is wrong with the user itself.
- Researched for TFS Error codes without anything useful, at leat to me, showing up

After wasting nearly a whole day researching and trying to understand where I'm wrong and what I misunderstood I'm reaching out for your help.

Comment: Create an other new team, when create, set the team like [the pictures](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AopgZUVNxLwJgUNXsV2VuzyWFIE7) shows. Then add users again to test again. Tell me the results. Please use IE browser to test.

Comment: Try to clean the caches on TFS server side(c:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache)  and caches at your browsers.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT caches cleared, team created like your picture, used IE for creatin/access test -> same result as descriped in my question :(

Comment: In other team project, does this issue also exists?

Comment: I try to reproduce your issue in my TFS by following the steps you provide above and everything is well in my environment. Can you think of anyother thing special?

Comment: Just used the repair option of tfs installer -> nothing changed;
Other collection, new team -> works;
Same collection, other team project -> works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like it seems every other team project and collection behaves correctly.

I'm now reusing an existing and working tfs group and moved to directly give permissions to teams instead of tfs groups. So I can keep different permissions per team everywhere but for the team project itself because all teams share the same tfs group.

I hope that the update to TFS 2017.2 maybe solves the issue in the future. For now I have to live with this workaround as this is our main team project.

I'll update this question as soon as I have any update.

Comment: Looking forward to the update. Please mark it as the answer. Thanks.